# How to show express js logs in heroku associated with a request id

Tags: express, heroku, logging, morgan

I am using express js in my server side and it is hosted in heroku. I have used morgan to attach a user id for each request. Although it shows up in the heroku logs just like a console log statement, I am not able to find out to which request this output belongs to.

```js
// req.headers['X-Request-ID] was undefined intially. 

morgan.token('userId', function getId(req) {
    req.headers['X-Request-ID'] = uuid.v4();
    if (req.user) {
        return `userId: ${req.userId} requestId: ${req.headers['X-Request-ID']}`
    }
});

// This is my actual request for which I am trying to track the userId 
app.post("/api/car", parseForm, csrfProtection, auth.protected, (request, response) => {

});
```

The requestID genereated in this function in not used by heroku. Instead heroku creates one by itself although [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id) says that requestId will be consumed if one is set in the request header.

Please help how to associate more information for a request in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

req.headers['x-request-id'] had the heroku generated request Id.